# read from subprocess output python

Tags: python, popen

I am running a subprocess using 'Popen'. I need to block till this subprocess finishes and then read its output.

```
p = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, encoding="utf-8")
p.communicate():
output = p.stdout.readline()
print(output)
```

I get an error that

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

How can I read the output after the subprocess finishes, I do not want to use poll() though as the subprocess takes time and I would need to wait for its completion anyway.

Comment: `p.communicate()` returns the output.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using `subprocess.run()` or the legacy `subprocess.check_output()`? You should avoid `Popen` if you can precisely because it's tricky to get right.

Comment: @jasonharper, `p.communicate()` returns `bound method Popen.communicate of <subprocess.Popen object at 0x105e84e10`, not the output of the subprocess code

Comment: `output, error = p.communicate()` should work, that output looks like you are just printing `p.communicate` (without the parentheses).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
p = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, encoding="utf-8")
output, error = p.communicate()

print(output)
if error:
    print('error:', error, file=sys.stderr)
```

However, [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) is preferred these days:

```
p = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

print("output:", p.stdout)

if proc.stderr:
    print("error:", p.stderr, file=sys.stderr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).  It returns the output of the command.