# python subprocess not capturing stdout

Tags: python

i'm trying to capture all output when running a python application using subprocess.  i've tried several variants using both subprocess.run and subprocess.Popen.  The python app that runs, executes a perl script and this output is captured.

```
import subprocess as sp

print("some data")
print("some data")

x = subprocess.run(['script.py', 'some', 'options'], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)

proc_out = sp.stdout
proc_err = sp.stderr
```

I've also tried adding '> out 2>&1' to the list, tried with capture_output=True, tried redirecting stdout/stderr.  The odd thing is that the print statements I'm trying to capture no longer display.

so, it's a python app (which output is captured), that uses subprocess to call another python app (unable to capture it's output), which in turn calls a perl function (which output is captured).

I've been through most of the threads that referenced capturing all data, but still no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: [My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53965917/streaming-read-from-subprocess) is overkill, but may provide a new starting point for you.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like my problem is resolved by adding python as the first element of the list.  subprocess.run(['python', cmd, args...)  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
command = "your command"
proc = subprocess.Popen([command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
```

You need .communicate(), which writes input then reads all output and waits for the subprocess to exit before continuing execution in current/main thread