# get and store stdout printf() function from c/c++ in python

Tags: python, c++, printf, stdout

I've got a OpenCL program with some printf() function and this program run over pyOpenCL. I want to store the stdout in a variable. My actual code to try achieve this is:

```
from io import StringIO # Python3 use: from io import StringIO
import sys
old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = mystdout = StringIO()
# fpga_conv = conv2d.Matmul(H, fpga_mtx, s_mask_ref.astype(np.int32), 1, 0)
# Call to the OpenCL program via pyOpenCL
fpga_ref = conv2d.Matmul(H_ans, fpga_mtx, s_mask_ans.astype(np.int32), 1, 1, (H_h, H_w))
sys.stdout = old_stdout
string = mystdout.getvalue() # Store stdout in a var
```

But only catchs the python *print()* stdout. It's possible get all the stdout? The only way that I've found is running the script in bash with the instruction `python module.py &> "ref.txt"` that stores the printf() stdout in ref.txt file. I need to run the program via IDE (Spyder in this case), not in the bash terminal. 
Any sugesstion or trick? Thx!

Comment: Yes. With stderr the output is empty

Comment: Hi @Prune I don't want redirect the output to a file. In my question I say that python module.py &> "ref.txt" work's perfectly but i need execute in the IDE, not in the bash terminal.

Comment: Okay; I reopened.  I suspect that what you'll want is a subprocess whose output you take as the process output.  See Popen documentation.  You can also work your way through the logic in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53965917/streaming-read-from-subprocess) -- I needed to monitor the output as it came through; you can use some of the other links to find a simple redirection.

Comment: Thx @Prune! I've answered my question with a solution via wurlitzer module.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found a solution via *wurlitzer* module -> https://github.com/minrk/wurlitzer

Works perfectly and only needs 2 or 3 lines of code. The example for my question is (with StringIO):

```
out = StringIO()
with pipes(stdout=out, stderr=STDOUT):
    w_fpga_ref = conv2d.Matmul(w_H_ans, fpga_mtx, w_s_mask_ans.astype(np.int32), 1, 1, (w_H_h, w_H_w))
x = out.getvalue()
```