# Integer formatting in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to get info about how much GPU % is currently used.
I'm running script below and get result.

```
import os


get_total_gpu = 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\\nvmdi.inf_amd64_36ae6ddd01b54f49\\nvidia-smi ' \
               '--query-gpu=memory.total--format=csv'


val=os.system(get_total_gpu )

print(val)
```

```
memory.total [MiB]
4096 MiB
1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

However, the result is in weird format and I cannot get the value from it (4096 MiB. I have GTX 1650).
I ran type(val) and it gives me class int. How can this be an integer? This more looks like a formatted string. Please explain me what's happening here and how can I get the number.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [read from subprocess output python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51660091/read-from-subprocess-output-python)

Comment: the return value of `system` is the exit code of the process, not it's captured standard or error output

Comment: The first two lines of your output are from running the command in your ``get_total_gpu`` string. The ``1`` in the third line is from your ``print(val)`` - please read the docs on the things you are using, don't make weird assumption. As @Homer512 pointed out, you should use a different method to get the return value of your command string and then you'll have to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its in csv format, so

```py
import os
import csv
import subprocess

# Command to get total GPU memory using nvidia-smi
get_total_gpu = 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\nvmdi.inf_amd64_36ae6ddd01b54f49\\nvidia-smi --query-gpu=memory.total --format=csv'

# Run the command and capture the output
output = subprocess.check_output(get_total_gpu, shell=True, text=True)

# Split the output into lines
lines = output.strip().split('\n')

# Use csv.reader to parse the CSV data
csv_reader = csv.reader(lines)

# Skip the header row if it exists
next(csv_reader)

# Read the second row
second_row = next(csv_reader)

# Get the value from the first column
value = second_row[0]

# Convert the value to an integer (assuming it's a number)
value_as_int = int(value)

# Do something with value_as_int
print(value_as_int)
```